# Changing the user picture in Ubuntu menu

Tags: login-screen, user-profile

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.
I want to change the user picture in the 'fast user switching menu'.

I've followed [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47186/is-there-a-way-to-change-user-picture-in-xubuntu-and-actually-display-it-on-log) and managed to change the picture on the log-on screen by changing ~/.face.

However, when I click the cogwheel in the top right of the screen, a menu drops down which includes my username and **old** picture. Is there a way to change this smaller menu picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user picture in the quick switch menu is the same as the picture linked with the user account. So if you go to your account settings and change the picture for your account there, it will update in the quick switch menu aswell. (might require a logout or restart to actually update the picture shown)

Comment: Changing the picture via User Accounts is identical to overwriting the ~/.face file, which is what I'd done. It seems I needed to restart the machine, rather than just log out and back in again, which is what I'd tried.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way where you don't need to change ~/.face

1. Click on your username in the top menu bar (probably right next to
   your clock and other indicators)
2. Click on User Accounts
3. Select the appropriate account
4. Click on the picture
5. Click on browse for more pictures
6. List item
7. Click on browse for more pictures
8. Select the correct picture
9. Logout & log back in

Et voila!